# Resources for One-Loop Calculation in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

I am recently trying to study the calculation on one-loop diagrams in QED. Since the most resources i found where rather cryptic since they where very very general i wanted to ask whether or not there are good papers or textbooks about that topic (especially for beginners)?

**My Background:**
I am a student in the 6th semester in physics. I do know how to calculate tree level feynman diagrams but i have only little understanding of QFT in general (Quantised Klein-Gordon-Field and classical field theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was doing my first course in QFT during my undergraduate, I referred to "**A first Book of Quantum Field Theory by Amitabha Lahiri and Palash B. Pal**". This is written in very simple language and you can find almost all the important topics in this textbook. If you want to read through much detailed version of QFT, I would recommend **Advanced Quantum Mechanics by Franz Schwabl** or **Introduction to Quantum Field Theory by Michael E. Peskin**. The latter one is quite heavy and I would not recommend this if you are not comfortable with the mathematics of QFT.

Comment: I disagree about Peskin. It is a perfectly accessible book, providing the student has a solid mathematical grasp of the prerequisites, it does not require any prior knowledge of QFT.